# Photon absorbtion in water as a function of wave length

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, water

Say you emit photons with wavelength $\lambda$ measured in nano meters from a point source with power output $P$ measured in watts. Say you then place a photon receiver at distance $d$ from the point source. Also this happens entirely within water. How does one calculate the power received by the receiver given the wavelength?

Comment: Photons are not attenuated. They are absorbed, transmitted or reflected. You should use classical electromagnetism.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law

Comment: @ChemEng, Thanks. This is helpful, however, how can I incorporate the frequency into the formula on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Beer-Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) determines how radiation propagates in an absorbing medium $-$ with an exponential decay in $d$, for which the characteristic decay length $L$ depends on the [absorptivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_attenuation_coefficient) of the medium. The dependence of the absorptivity on the wavelength is known as the absorption spectrum of the material.

For water (as for all materials), this dependence can change significantly depending on what spectral range one is looking at. Wikipedia has a useful overview page, [Electromagnetic absorption by water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water), but a good summary is the following spectrum, showing $1/L$ as a function of $\lambda$:

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Image source: Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Absorption_spectrum_of_liquid_water.png)</sup>